# GWT collections performance and recommended practices

Tags: gwt, collections, guava

What is the best way and/or recommended practices for working with collections in GWT, specially if looking for performance?

The options I have found so far are:

- JRE emulated collections. The most
  natural way for a Java developer but,
  in GWT team words "not an ideal match
  for the constraints of running inside
  browsers, especially mobile
  browsers". A performance comparaison
  can be found [here](http://lgrammel.blogspot.com/2010/09/gwt-arraylist-hashset-and-jsarray.html) and [here](http://blog.nikosd.com/2010/09/benchmarking-gwt-collections-emulation.html)
- [GWT Lightweight Collections](http://code.google.com/p/google-web-toolkit/wiki/LightweightCollections).
  Between other improvements they
  promised to bring minimum size of
  compiled script and absolute maximum
  speed. However there are no news
  regarding this project for 7 months.
- [Guava Libraries](http://code.google.com/p/guava-libraries/) Is it safe to
  use Guava in GWT? If so, does it
  brings real performance improvement?

Any other alternatives?

Many thanks

Comment: Thanks for the link. I will also update the post with a link backwards to this thread!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

If you're looking for absolute optimal performance on the browser, you should use something like Lightweight Collections -- native JS arrays and maps only, and all contained objects as JavaScriptObjects (overlay types).

However, this will severely limit your coding efficiency, since they aren't at all as easy to use as JRE collections. There is no `contains()`, no enhanced for loops, none of the niceties of Java. And after all, "the niceties of Java" are presumably why you're programming in GWT and not JS.

Guava doesn't aim to bring any particular efficiency benefits to a GWT app, it mostly just provides a simpler coding experience, and occasionally a tiny optimization here and there that you may not have considered. Guava is not optimized for GWT, it's merely available on GWT.

So, it's up to you. If you want to have the convenience of using regular Java collections, you should use Guava. If you want the absolute fastest performance, do everything in native collections.

Answer (score 3):

Agree with previous answer and providing some additional details:

GWT Lightweight collections designed to be client-side only. If you will want to transfer those using RPC mechanism you will likely end in the exception.

Another approach to speed up your JavaScript is to use Arrays instead of Collections where it is possible both for transport and processing. Arrays are closer to its JavaScript analogues and GWT does not compile-in too much wrapping code for compatibility purposes.

Would not expect any performance benefits from Guava as well.